# Image processing after edge detect in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I use canny to detect edge.But, as the quality of image is bad, a lot of noise is as below:
[image]

Origin image is this.
[image]

I just want the rectangle edges. As the edge I want to detect is so regular(like bricks). I wonder if there were some image process algorithms that could help me?

Note that some edge in image is so week, use a GaussianBlur may make these edge hard to be detected.

Thanks for all reply.

Comment: original image please. and state the *purpose* of this. why do you do this?

Comment: we'd need to see the orginal image but usually I would smooth the image prior to edge detection to remove noise,

Comment: Sorry, i forget. Now I have add original image.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint: it could be useful to strongly blur the image horizontally and vertically to obtain "clean" rows. From this you could reconstruct the grid and possibly inspect every cell.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*strong blur in one direction*" is indeed a good idea, but it may either wipe some edges completely, or it will keep some black blocks as this image is noisy, these two side effects can be seen [here](https://i.imgur.com/KZWaOei.png).

Comment: @Bilal: I did not say that the next operation is binarization, did I ?

Comment: I'm talking about **blur** itself, the image is just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @Bilal: the blur is on purpose, to **strengthen** the edges of interest, as it improves their SNR.